# A database error occurred error number: 1048 Column 'captcha_time' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

please help to remove following error

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'captcha_time' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `captcha_table` (`captcha_time`, `captcha_ip_address`, `captcha_word`) VALUES (NULL, '27.60.102.123', NULL)

Filename: models/dashboard/Common_model.php

Line Number: 13
```

Comment: What's unclear about "*Column 'captcha_time' cannot be null*"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a NULL into column captcha_time, if you add a value there it would fix it, but your questions doest give me clarity about it, also if you disable NOT NULL constraint on captcha_table you will be able to insert null values in captcha_time, you should analyze what is correct for you.

```
 INSERT INTO `captcha_table` (`captcha_time`, `captcha_ip_address`, `captcha_word`) VALUES (1234, '27.60.102.123', NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the folder "/captcha" is either not on your server or has the wrong permissions set.

```
set your folder permission to 775 or 777(testing purpose)
```

or change folder owner

```
chown yourUserName:www-data -R yourWebSiteFolder/*
```

if the image path doesn't exist, or isn't writeable the create_captcha() function returns false, have a look in the captcha helper.